# Grid cell is collecting data before start searching

Tags: google-app-maker

[image]

I'm trying to use the user picker to collect several data as entered and then store the data into the grid cell to show. But Now, My grid cells is showing empty cells even before I start searching. and the data is empty. 
The employee Name "OnValueChange" code is "addTrainee(widget, newValue);"

```
  var ds = app.pages.PracticePage.descendants.Grid1.datasource;
  var traineesEmails = ds.items.map(function(item) {
    return item.PrimaryEmail;
  });
  return traineesEmails.indexOf(primaryEmail);


}





function deleteTrainee(primaryEmail) {


 var testBox = app.pages.PracticePage.descendants.TestBox;


  //Test
  console.log ("Email: "+primaryEmail);
  console.log("Before: "+ testBox.value);

testBox.value =  testBox.value.replace(primaryEmail,"");
  console.log("After: "+ testBox.value);



  //Test


  var index = getTraineeIndex(primaryEmail);
  if (index === -1) {
    return;
  }  

   var ds = app.pages.PracticePage.descendants.Grid1.datasource;
   ds.items.splice(index, 1);



}





function addTrainee(userPickerWidget, newValue) {



if (!newValue) {
    console.log("Checking for new Value Statement.");
    return;
  } 

  if (getTraineeIndex(newValue.PrimaryEmail) > -1) {
    console.log("Cheking for repeatation");
    return;
  } 











  var ds = app.pages.PracticePage.descendants.Grid1.datasource;

  ds.items.push({
    FullName: newValue.FullName,
    PrimaryEmail: newValue.PrimaryEmail,

  });

 console.log("Pushed Email Address: ", newValue.PrimaryEmail);


  var testBox = app.pages.PracticePage.descendants.TestBox;



   if(testBox.value === null){
   testBox.value = newValue.PrimaryEmail;
     console.log("No data in text box");
  }  
  else {
    testBox.value = testBox.value + ", "+ newValue.PrimaryEmail;
  console.log("Enter data in text box");
  }

  userPickerWidget.value = null;
}


function addNewData(PrimaryEmail){

  console.log("running AddNewData function ");

  while(typeof(PrimaryEmail) != undefined){
     console.log("returning Primary Email: "+ PrimaryEmail);
    return PrimaryEmail;

  }


}
```

and the grid cell doesn't have any event. The text value of the label inside the grid cell. which supposed to collect the email address is "addNewData(@datasource.item['PrimaryEmail'])" 
[image]

what could be the reason behind it? and How to fix it?

Comment: It seems that you may be trying to accomplish something similar to what is available in the Training Hub template provided here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/training-hub. I might suggest taking a look at this template and seeing if this might address your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am actually recreate something very much similar to that. I looked at the problem. But couldn't find any problem in mine. pretty much same as the Training hub. Since I directly copied many parts from training hub.

Comment: I would suggest updating your question to include bindings on the Employee Name field. But my guess is that you don't need a onvaluechange event for the employee name field and that is why you are generating a mostly empty grid because of that piece of code.

Comment: If I delete the onValueChange field for the Employee field. the only thing that happened is that I cannot attach my values on the grid cell anymore. But I still have the empty grids. So my guess is the problem is in the grid. The only binding in the value of the email address is " addNewData(@datasource.item['PrimaryEmail'])"

Comment: Ok, lets try a different approach. What is the datasource 'ChangeSystem' which is the datasource that your grid is tied to? What is the datasource of the parent element that the grid is located in, is it a form for 'ChangeSystem' or something else? If you are trying to assign some type of relation here or a field value that points to multiple individuals, then it seems you are over complicating things going with your current approach. You might also want to consider changing your userpicker settings to check 'Is Record' that way you can eliminate your check index function all together.

Comment: I was doing some debugging using console. I found that My Grid is searching for value even before I enter any value in the employee field. And found nothing so just returning undefined value. How to stop it data searching value??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201218/discussion-between-markus-malessa-and-rrrrrrrrr).